# Owncloud - Custom file in Skeleton directory

Tags: owncloud

I set and I am using ownCloud.

I want to put an pdf file in my skeleton directory. So, when I add an new user, this file appears with 0kb.

The documentation does not tell nothing about this error.

And I cant see what i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! The custom file did not have access permission